# merge multiples array with javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I need to send multiple array as parameters, not only 2 (yes I'm using _underscore in order to check for duplicate entries)

```
function arrayMerge(arr1, arr2) {
    arr1 = Object.prototype.toString.call(arr1) === '[object Array]' ? arr1 : [];
    arr2 = Object.prototype.toString.call(arr2) === '[object Array]' ? arr2 : [];   
    return _.uniq(arr1.concat(arr2));
}
```

How can I achieve this ? I would like to send not 2, but multiples arrays as parameters.

Comment: You can randomly refer to any function argument via the "builtin" `arguments` array: `arguments[0] === arr1` in your case. Iterate over `arguments` to get each array.

Comment: You can directly use `_.union()` for that `_.union([1,4,6,9], [1,4,12,5], [5,0,10,100], [1]).join("") === _.uniq([1,4,6,9].concat([1,4,12,5]).concat([5,0,10,100]).concat([1])).join("")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version that also checks for array type like in your original code:

```
function arrayMerge() {
    return _.chain(arguments).filter(_.isArray).flatten().unique().value();
}
```

The demo is below.

```js
function arrayMerge() {
    return _.chain(arguments).filter(_.isArray).flatten().unique().value();
}

var result = arrayMerge([1,2,3],[1,3,4],'test',[2,3,4,5]);

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `arguments`. The variable `arguments` is an array of all the arguments passed to a function. So you can try this:

```
function merge() {
  return _.uniq(Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arguments));
}
```

I have no experience with underscore but this should work.

Due to the behavior of `concat`, calling `merge([3, 4, 5], null, 6)` will result in `[3, 4, 5, null, 6]`.

To ensure that all are arrays:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(arguments[i]) !== '[object Array]') {
    throw new Error(arguments[i] + " is not an array"); // Or do whatever you want
  }
}
```

Comment: @soktinpk You might want to leave a comment for the OP, it looks like they've never accepted an answer before.

Answer (score 1):

Soktinpk's answer is best for ES5.

If you are able to use ES6, you can make it a bit more explicit using rest parameters

```
function merge(...arrays) {
  return _.uniq(Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arrays));
}
```